# Laravel 5.1 Linkification / clickable links in user-entered text

Tags: php, laravel, input, laravel-blade

I'm currently working on a Laravel 5.1 project and using the Blade template engine.

Blade offers a syntax that generally escapes all user input like so:

```
{{ $value }}
```

I'd now like to escape **everything, but URLs** from user input when outputting it in order to make links clickable.

For example, the link

```
http://google.de/
```

should be caught (i.e. by  a certain RegEx) and transformed into:

```
<a href="http://google.de">http://google.de/</a>
```

I do have the possibility of doing it in my AppServiceProvider using plain PHP (traverse the text, replace text links with clickable HTML elements and replace everything that is *not* a link with it's respective HTML-Entity counterparts).

However, since this is a framework and frameworks are designed to lessen the burden of re-inventing the wheel over and over I'd expect there to be some better solution than doing what I'd do in every other PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I am getting it clear, but

```
{!! $value !!}
```

will prevent the default blade escape. So, if within your blade view you have a `$link` variable equals to `http://google.de/`, you can surely show it unescaped:

```
<a href="{!! $link !!}">{!! $link !!}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but you missed the point. What I asked for was "escape everything, but URLs" (see the question text) - so that I can turn them from plain text representation into clickable links.

Comment: @RobinHeller Ok, so I was right, I didn't get it right. Are you looking for something like [this](https://github.com/misd-service-development/php-linkify) ?

Comment: I tried @MisterP's answer by using linkify, I believe his answer should be marked as the answer since no accepted answer was ever decided.